# Regular expression - allow digits but no dash punctuation mark

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression. Here is my basic requirement:

1. Only allow 11 numbers.
2. Cannot have a dash (`-`) inside these 11 numbers.

Here is the regular expression that I wrote:

```
\d{11}[^-]
```

Examples: 
a) 12345654321 => **Valid** 
b) 123-4567890 => **Invalid**
c) -1234567890 => **Invalid**
d) 1234567890- => **Invalid**

I didn't get the proper result. How should I correct it?

Comment: Looks like you could use a regex tutorial. Your current attempt will match 11 digits followed by a single character that is not a `-`. But why does rule #2 even exist? #1 means there are no dashes anyway.

Comment: @Michael could you post some example strings for valid and invalid matches?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I already post some examples for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^\d{11}$
```

this should do it.......
With anchors